# SSRS Drill Through report using expression report name invalid

Tags: reporting-services

In a text box I am using an expression for a goto report action based on a parameter. A report will be openend based on the value of the parameter:

iif(Parameters!Par_Sub.Value = "Werkgever.Bedrijf",
"reportsubtwo.rdl",
nothing
)

In preview however I get the following message:

the Drillthrough Report Name for the text box  is not valid. Item names cannot contain the following reserved characters ;?:@&=+$,*<>|". (rsInvalidReportNameCharacters)

What could be wrong?  The report reportsubtwo exists and does not contain any special characters, I am running into a dead end obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution,  the = character before the IIF statement is missing,

=iif(Parameters!Par_Sub.Value = "Werkgever.Bedrijf", "reportsubtwo.rdl", nothing )

is the right syntax. Curiously there was no syntax error message displayed after completing the goto report action, but this vague message about the report name containing reserverd characters during previewing the report.